Variable won't update on previous view
I have a view (OrderView) which leads to another view via navigationLink. In this new view (StarterView) a variable "total" is updated. This works as I have added a print statement to see that it is updated. When I leave this view back to OrderView, the variable Total which is in a Text(totalViewModel.total) is still at 0. Does anyone know why this won't update?
Thanks
class TotalViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var total: Float = 0
}

struct OrderView: View {
    
    
    
    @ObservedObject var totalViewModel: TotalViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Text("£\(totalViewModel.total)")


}```


Please show a [mcve] - something I can copy-paste into a new Xcode project and reproduce your issue.

@Sweeper I can but you may have to create the list yourself as I pull this from Firestore: https://pastebin.com/76RqM42y

That is not minimal at all. It is your responsibility to isolate the problem, and remove as much of the irrelevant parts of the code as possible. Your code should also not depend on FIrebase unless it is required to reproduce the problem.

My apologies: https://pastebin.com/H8hWVtFf @Sweeper

You cannot initialize the property wrapper @State and @State-/@ObservedObject just by assigning the default value. You have to create a new object and assign it to the backing instance variable. Actually the init method is not needed at all. And don't post code on external services, show it in the question.

Try @State var total = 0.0

Have a look at this Apple link  Monitoring data for how to manage data in your app. Basically you need to declare @StateObject private var totalViewModel = TotalViewModel() in your parent view, and pass it to OrderView using .environmentObject(totalViewModel) or directly using OrderView(totalViewModel: totalViewModel) (no need for your init)
